# Assign value on nested object using value from sibling

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects

I have a config object with a token. Inside, there is a nested `headers` object that needs to reference the token. I am unable to use `this`, as shown below (comes up as undefined), and `config.token` doesn't work either.

```
var config = {
  token: 'abc123',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'bearer ' + this.token
  }
}
```

I need to be able to reassign `config.token` and have `config.headers.Authorization` update automatically with the new value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it with [`get` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) :

```js
var config = {
  token: 'abc123',
  get headers () {
    return {
      'Authorization': 'bearer ' + this.token
    }
  }
}

console.log(config);
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about the get operator. Thank you, this works!